# Error with the shell script

Tags: shell

I have a Django project. THere is a function in it which aggregate blog posts and this function is attached to the url. And I need this function(url) run in appointed time. For that I use cron I wrote the shell script but I'm noob in shell scripting and it doesn't work.
Please, tell me what's wrong with it?

```
OUT=$( curl -qSfsw '\n%{http_code}' url  ) 2>/dev/null
RET=$?
if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "Adding of blogs was failed: $(echo "$OUT" | tail -n1 )" | mail -s "Adding of blogs was failed" baartt11@gmail.com
else
echo "Blogs were added successfully" | head -n-1 | mail -s "Blogs were added successfully" baartt11@gmail.com
fi
```

The error text:

```
./update_blogs.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./update_blogs.sh: line 7: `fi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using pipe "|", for this reason, it considers that this is the end of the comande if. to solve this problem you have to group commandes, using "(" and ")" :

```
OUT=$( curl -qSfsw '\n%{http_code}' http://appbrainiac.com/api/daily_blogs_update/  ) 2>/dev/null
RET=$?
if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]]; then
(  echo "Adding of blogs was failed: $(echo "$OUT" | tail -n1 )" | mail -s "Adding of blogs was failed" baartt11@gmail.com )
else
( echo "Blogs were added successfully" | head -n-1 | mail -s "Blogs were added successfully" baartt11@gmail.com )
fi
```

Comment: Uh, no. The statements within if/then/else do not need to be grouped with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this problem when I used your script (cut & pasted it) and ran it through `sh -n scriptname` (which tests the sh syntax).

However, I could cause a similar error, when using DOS line endings (`\r\n`). Was this script somehow transferred from a Windows machine? Was it edited with a Windows editor?

To verify if this is the problem, run

```
od -bc scriptname
```

and look if there are *Carriage Return* `\r` characters in your script. If so, you can remove them with

```
dos2unix scriptname
```